# Concatenation of character string and variable SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

```sql
SET @Result = '{ "host_name": "' + @hostname + '", "status": 15 }'
```

Could you explain to me what we get with the value of Result please? If we assume that hostname = "machine1".

To test this, I created a table and a Stored Procedure and Print the value of Result :

```
CREATE TABLE utilisateur
(
    
    nom VARCHAR(100),
    prenom VARCHAR(100),    
    age VARCHAR(5),
    
)
INSERT INTO utilisateur (prenom, nom, age)
 VALUES
 ('Rébecca', 'Armand', 24)
go

 CREATE PROCEDURE [sp_DB] 
  @hostname nvarchar(50),
  @Result nvarchar(2000) OUTPUT

AS
  select age as a from utilisateur where nom = 'Armand' 
  SET @hostname = 'machine1'
  SET @Result = '{ "host_name": "' + @hostname + '", "a": 15 }' 
  print @Result

EXEC [sp_DB]@hostname ='machine1',@Result = 'test';
```

But the execution does not display the content of the Result variable.

PS : I use sqlfiddle.com/ to execute the code

Comment: your printing the results, you want to select it to be returned as a result set from the SP

Comment: Can you show the code that actually _executes_ the stored procedure? Note that many GUIs like sqlfiddle and dbfiddle will not always display `PRINT` messages, so think about what you _actually_ want to do with that. BTW [working fine for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c6ccdf520387ea43f412dd1e74a93edb).

Comment: Can you add the link to your sqlfiddle?

Comment: Code corrected I added EXEC [sp_DB]

Comment: This works fine in SSMS; the `PRINT` is shown on the messages pane. As mentioned, don't rely on things like Fiddles for realistic IDE behaviour; they aren't IDEs. If you want to properly test your code, install SQL Server locally and grab ADS or SSMS.

Comment: You need to add `GO` between the procedure body and the `EXEC` call, otherwise that `EXEC` call has just become part of the body of the procedure. A procedure must be created / altered in its own batch.

Comment: Also you should create JSON properly `SET @Result = (SELECT host_name = @hostname, status = 15 FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the output variable on the procedure calling scope, and use the keyword OUTPUT to retrieve output the value.
So if you do it like:

```
declare @result_out nvarchar(2000)
EXEC [sp_DB]@hostname ='machine1',@Result=@result_out OUTPUT;
select @result_out as [Result]
```

It will work.